# ejabberd BOSH search brings nothing

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api

We're trying to switch from Openfire to ejabberd XMPP server.
I have ejabberd installed with default options on my local Windows 10 workstation.
I set

```
  mod_vcard:
    search: true
```

I registered a couple of users using ejabberd ReST API. I also set some ***vcard*** values for those users (my understanding is that vcard entries are necessary for ejabberd search to work, correct?)
Using Postman, I can confirm that there are vcards for user "testfouoles":

```
POST http://localhost:5281/api/get_vcard
Body:
{
      "host": "planetrisk.com",
      "user": "testfouoles",
      "name": "FN"
}

Response:
{
    "content": "Test UnclassifiedFouoLes"
}
```

Besides **FN**, **EMAIL**, **NICKNAME**, and **NICK** vcards are set. vcards seems to be case-sensitive, so I set both small lettters and capital letters variants, because I'm not sure which variants are used by search. I also set ***vcard2*** values for **N FAMILY** and **N GIVEN**.

For Openfire, we were using CandyJs with a custom Search plugin. For now we continue to use it with ejabberd.
**For test purposes, I set**

```
  mod_vcard:
    search: true
    allow_return_all: true
```

This way, *search operations with empty input fields return **all users** who added some information to their vCard* (according to [ejabberd docs](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#mod-vcard)).

Our CandyJS Search plugin issues the following POST request to ejabberd BOSH listener:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5443/bosh?b=101
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:5443
...
Request Payload
<body rid='55271928' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='5633a7a6184041b173970798227fddadea5e8742'>
  <iq type='set' id='search2' to='vjud.planetrisk.com' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'>
      <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
        <field var='first'><value/></field>
        <field var='last'><value/></field>
        <field var='nick'><value/></field>
        <field var='email'><value/></field>
        <field var='fn'><value/></field>
      </x>
    </query>
  </iq>
</body>
```

And ejabberd responds with vcard data of the only registered user (besides the requesting user):

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
  <iq xml:lang='en' to='army.dudeFOUO(at)everbridge.mil@planetrisk.com/planetrisk_Candy_b4a02de8' from='vjud.planetrisk.com' type='result' id='search2' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'>
      <x type='result' xmlns='jabber:x:data'>
        <title>Search Results for vjud.planetrisk.com</title>
        <reported>
          <field var='jid' type='text-single' label='Jabber ID'/>
          <field var='fn' type='text-single' label='Full Name'/>
          <field var='first' type='text-single' label='Name'/>
          <field var='middle' type='text-single' label='Middle Name'/>
          <field var='last' type='text-single' label='Family Name'/>
          <field var='nick' type='text-single' label='Nickname'/>
          <field var='bday' type='text-single' label='Birthday'/>
          <field var='ctry' type='text-single' label='Country'/>
          <field var='locality' type='text-single' label='City'/>
          <field var='email' type='text-single' label='Email'/>
          <field var='orgname' type='text-single' label='Organization Name'/>
          <field var='orgunit' type='text-single' label='Organization Unit'/>
        </reported>
        <item>
          <field var='jid'><value>testfouoles@planetrisk.com</value></field>
          <field var='fn'><value>Test UnclassifiedFouoLes</value></field>
          <field var='last'><value>UnclassifiedFouoLes</value></field>
          <field var='first'><value>Test</value></field>
          <field var='middle'><value/></field>
          <field var='nick'><value>testfouoles</value></field>
          <field var='bday'><value/></field>
          <field var='ctry'><value/></field>
          <field var='locality'><value/></field>
          <field var='email'><value>testfouoles@planetrisk.com</value></field>
          <field var='orgname'><value/></field>
          <field var='orgunit'><value/></field>
        </item>
      </x>
    </query>
  </iq>
</body>
```

Everything works fine so far. Now, if I submit a search request with non-empty search criteria, regardless of having  allow_return_all: true or false, search does not find anything:

```
Request Payload
<body rid='839156118' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='39d0d2e120960757f97eeb15488ba6820b509bf7'>
  <iq type='set' id='search2' to='vjud.planetrisk.com' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'>
      <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
        <field var='first'><value>UnclassifiedFouoLes</value></field>
        <field var='last'><value>UnclassifiedFouoLes</value></field>
        <field var='nick'><value>UnclassifiedFouoLes</value></field>
        <field var='email'><value>UnclassifiedFouoLes</value></field>
        <field var='fn'><value>UnclassifiedFouoLes</value></field>
      </x>
    </query>
  </iq>
</body>
```

Here I tried to search for **"UnclassifiedFouoLes"** which is the correct value of N FAMILY. I tried to search for correct email, nick, etc - nothing works. ejabberd returns an empty result.

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
  <iq xml:lang='en' to='army.dudeFOUO(at)everbridge.mil@planetrisk.com/planetrisk_Candy_0d46391c' from='vjud.planetrisk.com' type='result' id='search2' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'>
      <x type='result' xmlns='jabber:x:data'>
        <title>Search Results for vjud.planetrisk.com</title>
        <reported>
          <field var='jid' type='text-single' label='Jabber ID'/>
          <field var='fn' type='text-single' label='Full Name'/>
          <field var='first' type='text-single' label='Name'/>
          <field var='middle' type='text-single' label='Middle Name'/>
          <field var='last' type='text-single' label='Family Name'/>
          <field var='nick' type='text-single' label='Nickname'/>
          <field var='bday' type='text-single' label='Birthday'/>
          <field var='ctry' type='text-single' label='Country'/>
          <field var='locality' type='text-single' label='City'/>
          <field var='email' type='text-single' label='Email'/>
          <field var='orgname' type='text-single' label='Organization Name'/>
          <field var='orgunit' type='text-single' label='Organization Unit'/>
        </reported>
      </x>
    </query>
    </iq>
  </body>
```

**So, why doesn't ejabberd find users by correctly supplied (?) search terms which matches vcard values? What am I doing wrong?**

I'm stuck. I cannot find any additional ejabberd documentation on [Jabber Search](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html). I don't understand how standard vcard field names correspond to standard Jabber Search field names (or maybe [Data Forms](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0004.html) field names?).

The same CandyJS Search plugin issues very similar request to Openfire XMPP server and gets results. The only difference is that Openfire requires some non-standard additions to search request payload to specify in which fields to search in:

```
<field var='Username'><value>1</value></field>
<field var='Name'><value>1</value></field>
<field var='Email'><value>1</value></field>
```

And Openfire returns results with an additional

```
<field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden"/>
```

clause. Does it give any clue?

**I'm stuck and really appreciate pointing me to the right direction.**

**Update:**

Actually, here is the first question:
When we send the following search request to XMPP server

```
<body rid='839156118' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'
sid='39d0d2e120960757f97eeb15488ba6820b509bf7'>
  <iq type='set'id='search2' to='vjud.planetrisk.com' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'>
      <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
        <field var='first'><value>UnclassifiedFouoLes</value></field>
        <field var='last'><value>UnclassifiedFouoLes</value></field>
        <field var='nick'><value>UnclassifiedFouoLes</value></field>
        <field var='email'><value>UnclassifiedFouoLes</value></field>
        <field var='fn'><value>UnclassifiedFouoLes</value></field>
      </x>
    </query>
 </iq>
</body>
```

Are search conditions combined by "OR" or by "AND"?
Do we search for a user who has ***any*** of field values ('first', 'last', 'nick', email', 'fn') equal to 'UnclassifiedFouoLes' or ***all*** the fields equal?

**Update 2:**
I'm trying to send a simple request (one without `<x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>`) from Postman to ejabberd:

```
<body rid='1106091871' xmlns='jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='2afabe5b07c316685e25a2d407617a534ca6b2bb'>
  <iq type='set' id='search2' to='vjud.planetrisk.com' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'><last>UnclassifiedFouoLes</last></query>
  </iq>
</body>
```

The result is always empty - it doesn't return any items. And there is a user with "last" vCard = "UnclassifiedFouoLes".

Why is it? Is "from" clause in request required?

Two existing clients can see each other and communicate in chat. But when I login as client1, grab sid and rid, insert them into Postman post, **result** is empty like

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='67c6c7ee389a99e3491bbeab9ab198766ffa5ca8' rid='1287825358'>
    <iq xmlns='jabber:client' type='set' id='search2' to='vjud.planetrisk.com'>
        <query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'>
            <last>UnclassifiedFouoLes</last>
        </query>
    </iq>
</body>
```

Comment: Options are combined with AND. You need to have all options matched.

Comment: I found that Openfire Search plugin implements the following extended search (https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html#extensibility) logic:
- If `<x xmlns='jabber:x:data'>`  XML clause is present in search request, it looks for <field var='search'><value>_a_search_term_</value></field>, then looks for search fields with values equal to to "1" or "true", replaces values of each of those with _a_search_term_ and effectively searches using OR: Username = _a_search_term_ OR Name = _a_search_term_ OR Email = _a_search_term_

Does ejabberd do something similar?

Comment: I think at least some XMPP client libraries (like Smack) submit search to XMPP server in that format...  https://github.com/igniterealtime/openfire-search-plugin/blob/master/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/plugin/SearchPlugin.java#L602

Comment: I'm trying to send a simple request (one without <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>) from Postman to ejabberd:  
    <body rid='1106091871' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='2afabe5b07c316685e25a2d407617a534ca6b2bb'><iq type='set' id='search2' to='vjud.planetrisk.com' xmlns='jabber:client'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'><last>UnclassifiedFouoLes</last></query></iq></body>
The result is always empty - it doesn't return any items. And there is a user with "last" vCard = "UnclassifiedFouoLes".  

Why is it?  Is "from" clause in request required?

Comment: ejabberd does not support this extended search added to Openfire. It is not a XEP standard and not documented. Regarding Bosh, you should not try to use it manually using Postman, as it is difficult to get right manually with the ID, etc. Bosh is not intended to be use as an API. It is intended to be use with an XMPP client.

Comment: Thanks again, @MickaëlRémond.  Yea, I understood that using Postman is not a good option because it's difficult to provide correct `rid`. I posted answer to myself below. My error with standard extended search request was not sending `<field type="hidden" var="FORM_TYPE"><value>jabber:iq:search</value></field>` clause. Openfire allowed tat omission, ejabberd did not.  
There are advantages in a non-standard way Openfire plugin implements search - I'm talking about it in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Simple type of search (one without `<x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">`) somehow returned error.

For extended search, it turned out, I was not sending

```
<field type="hidden" var="FORM_TYPE"><value>jabber:iq:search</value></field>
```

clause. That omission was working fine against Openfire, ejabberd requires it.

Still, [Openfire Search plugin](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/1.7.2/search/readme.html) provides convenience and efficiency which I didn't find in ejabberd: it allows a chat client to display one search box and then to search for the value user typed in several fields (search ***OR*** functionality). On a client side, you need to send search request like

```
<body rid='273260412' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='961w8ipmo2'>
  <iq type='set' id='search2' to='yourSearchDomain.com' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'>
      <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
        <field var='search'><value>your_search_term</value></field>
        <field var='Username'><value>1</value></field>
        <field var='Name'><value>1</value></field>
        <field var='Email'><value>1</value></field>
      </x>
    </query>
  </iq>
</body>
```

Openfire Search plugin would interpret this request as a command to perform three search requests: to find users with `Username` which matches `your_search_term`, then to find users with `Name` matching, and with `Email` matching. All three search results would be combined using logical **OR**.
Client only needs to send ***one*** Http search request to Openfire to search for `your_search_term` in ***three*** fields.  With ejabberd, client would need to send ***three*** Http requests...

It would be nice to implement similar functionality in ejabberd module...

Comment: Correct format for ejabberd extended search request was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243370/efficient-xmpp-user-search  
Thank you, @Uscher

Comment: Thanks for the details / explanation. If you feel it would make a good quality pull request, you may consider submit a patch to ejabberd project.

Comment: I'm going to buy a book and learn Erlang first (I'm .NET developer). Then maybe...